# Nonlinear Optimization with conditional statement

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I find Maximize doesn't work well under **conditional statement**. Here is an example. 
[image]

A car is driving up a slope. I want to find out the largest slope angle the car can drive upwards. I choose the slope angle `θ` and engine torque `τ` as decision variables. The friction force can be described by Coulomb friction model, which is  a conditional statement

[image]

The complete formulation is

[image]

Therefore, the Nonlinear Optimization can be solved by

```
  Maximize[{θ, 0 < θ < Pi/2 && 0 < τ < 2 && 
            If[τ/r < μs*G*Cos[θ], τ/r, μd G Cos[θ]] > G Sin[θ]}, {θ, τ}]
```

given the parameters:
      G = 70;
      r = 0.025;
      μs = 0.5;
      μd = 0.4;

Mathematica gives `θ=0.380506`,,which is ArcTan[μd], whereas the expected result should be `θ=0.46364`,which is ArcTan[μs].

Answer (score 2):

Try `If[c, x > z, y > z]` instead of `If[c, x, y] > z`:

```
G = 70; r = 0.025; μs = 0.5; μd = 0.4;
Maximize[{θ, 0 < θ < Pi/2 && 0 < τ < 2 && 
   If[τ/r < μs*G*Cos[θ], τ/r > G Sin[θ], μd G Cos[θ] > G Sin[θ]]}, {θ, τ}]
```

> ```
> {0.463648, {θ -> 0.463648, τ -> 0.782624}}
> ```

```
ArcTan[μs]
```

> ```
> 0.463648
> ```

Comment: :@ybeltukov,aha! Thanks. There is a trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just a long comment.
A bit annoying :

```
constr[x_, θ_] = 
  Piecewise[{{x - G Sin[θ], x < μs*G*Cos[θ]}, 
             {μd G Cos[θ] - G Sin[θ], x >= μs*G*Cos[θ]}
            }] ;

sol = NMaximize[Join[{θ, 0 < θ < Pi/2, 0 < τ < 2}, {constr[τ/r, θ] > 0}], {θ, τ}] 
(* {0.380506, {θ -> 0.380506, τ -> 1.08698}} *)
```

but

```
constr[τ/r, θ] /. sol[[2]]
(* -8.0802*10^-6 *)
```

Comment: It seems the piecewise method has the same answer as the if conditional statement.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I only wanted to stress that the constraints is not met, even though by a small number.

Comment: Is it because the friction function is not continuous? And, is there another way to impose the constraint?